# lookup() function in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, lookup, lookup-tables

i have two datasets, one is stored into Hive(smaller one further used as lookup table) and another is getting from spark streaming.

Now my requirement is perform some operations on these two datasets.

For eg:

dataset1:(which is stored in hive)

```
id     name  
101    steve
102    david
```

dataset2:(which is coming from spark streaming)

```
id   deprt   address

101   E01    NewYork
102   E02    London
```

whenever i get `101   E01    NewYork` from streaming i want combine two datasets and return the result like:

```
id  name  dept  address
101 steve E01  NewYork
```

Earlier, i have done this type of task with **Broadcast** variables and i am trying to exlpore this by using Hive lookup tables.

Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

assuming your hive lookup table is small since you have already been using it as a broadcast variable you can just create dataframe from reading the hive table using which you can perform the lookup.

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val lookupDF = hiveContext.sql("select * from your_hive_table").cache() //cache lookup data


ds.transform {
    rdd => 
        val df = rdd.toDF("c1","c2","c3")
        df.join(lookupDF, lookupDF("col") === df("col")).select("co1","col2","col3").rdd
}
```

Comment: And then do a foreachRDD on the stream and inside of it join with the `lookupDF`